# Error when trying to install 'rworldmap' and dependency 'fields'

Tags: r, field, rworldmap

When trying to install 'rworldmap' I get an error saying "there is no package called 'fields'". So I try to install 'fields' and when I do it says unpacked successfully and MD5 sums checked, but then an error saying compilation failed. Any advice? Here is exactly what comes up:

```
There is a binary version available but the source version
  is later:
       binary source needs_compilation
fields    9.0    9.6              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
y/n: y
installing the source package ‘fields’

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0100 3188k  100 3188k    0     0  3720k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3720k
* installing *source* package ‘fields’ ...
** package ‘fields’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c ExponentialUpperC.c -o ExponentialUpperC.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c addToDiagC.c -o addToDiagC.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c compactToMatC.c -o compactToMatC.o
clang -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c expfnC.c -o expfnC.o
gfortran-4.8   -fPIC  -g -O2  -c fieldsF77Code.f -o fieldsF77Code.o
make: gfortran-4.8: No such file or directory
make: *** [fieldsF77Code.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fields’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/fields’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fields’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/vx/ffhh4_sj0hj810kjht02f9bc0000gn/T/RtmpncjRcs/downloaded_packages’
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears you don't have  `gfortran` installed correctly. I'm guessing this is on a Mac, so go to the installation page and correct your setup if you want to compile from source. This is a link to the Mac `tools` page: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools

I admit to a bit of a puzzle about why this error was thrown, since my attempt to install from fields ver. 9.6 source in R version 3.4.3 showed no visible  "effort" to compile any fortran code. Maybe the Fortran messages are not sent to the console? Also worries me that you may be using an outdated version of R (3.2). That's two years old and may not be compatible with current version of packages. Older versions of `pkg::fields` are here:
https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/fields/

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded the latest version of R and now everything works fine!